# how to convert suit format to ttf or any other format?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, truetype

I have the license for the AntennaCond-Regular.suit font, and I am trying to convert it to other fonts using the font squirrel web-font generator: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

But the problem is that when I try to choose the .suit font format for conversion on the website, the file is not clickable, which means that I can't select this font. I have hoplessly searched the web for a free antenna Cond with another format, but I couldn't find it. And I have already paid for the font package, so I will not pay for it again on another website.

Is there something that I should do with the suit font format? is there some use that I don't know about the suit format? Thanks.

Comment: Try using this [Free online font converter](http://www.freefontconverter.com/)

Comment: just did :"Could not identity any fonts in the uploaded file, are you sure it's a font file?"

Comment: Sounds like your font file is corrupt(could explain why it wasn't working on FontSquirrel as well).